# ERROR TS6054: File '../contract/assembly/sensor_data.json.ts' not found

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I am trying to fill some function arguments with a .json file but when i try to build the contract in the Near Protocol the command window returns Error TS6054. I am importing the .json from the same dir with "import * as data from ../contract/assembly/sensor_data.json" I already modified the tsconfig.json and incuded the compileOperations: "resolveJsonModule": true,"esModuleInterop": true. But this still keeps happening. What else could i do?

This is my code:

```
import { PersistentSet, PersistentUnorderedMap } from "near-sdk-as";
 import * as data from '../../contract/assembly/sensor_data.json';
 
@nearBindgen
export class Sensor {
    sensorName: string;
    sensorType: string;
    ownerId: string;
    allowedUsers: PersistentSet<string>;
    userRequests: PersistentSet<string>;

    constructor(
        _ownerId: string,
        _sensorName: string,
        _sensorType: string,) {
        this.ownerId = _ownerId;
        this.sensorName = _sensorName;
        this.sensorType = _sensorType;
        this.allowedUsers = new PersistentSet<string>(this.sensorName + "A");
        this.userRequests = new PersistentSet<string>(this.sensorName + "U");
    }
    getArgs(): string {
        return "{}";
    }

    hasAccess(accountId: string): bool {
        return this.allowedUsers.has(accountId) || accountId ==  this.ownerId;
    }

    getRequests(): string {
        let array: Array<string> = this.userRequests.values();
        return array.join(",");
    }

    addRequest(accountId: string): void {
        this.userRequests.add(accountId);
    }
}

export class DHT11 extends Sensor{
id : number;
date: string;
temp: f32;
hum : f32
constructor(
    sensorName:string,
    sensorType:string,
    ownerId:string,
    _id : number,
    _date:string, 
    _temp:f32, 
    _hum: f32){
    super(sensorName,sensorType,ownerId)
    let n= 1
    for (n ; n < data.Data.length; n++) {
        const DHT11 = data.Data[n];
    this.id = DHT11.id;
    this.date = DHT11.date;
    this.temp = DHT11.temperature;
    this.hum = DHT11.humidity;
    }
    
}
getArgs(): string {
    return "{Dispositivo DHT11. Sensor que mide temperatura y humedad}";
}
getState(): string {
    
    return "{id:" + this.id.toString() + ", Date:"
    + this.date.toString() + ", Temperature:" + this.temp.toString()
    + ", Humidity:" + this.hum.toString() + "}";
}
}

export let sensorRegistry = new PersistentUnorderedMap<string, Sensor>("s");
export let DHT11Registry = new PersistentUnordered
```

Map<string, DHT11>("d");

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use AssemblyScript like TypeScript but you can't directly import JSON like that.

Instead you could consider loading the JSON into memory using the `includeBytes` helper as used in [this example](https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--meme-museum/blob/main/src/museum/assembly/index.ts#L6) and then loading / parsing it using one of these libraries:

- https://github.com/near/assemblyscript-json
- https://dev.to/assemblyscript/json-in-assemblyscript-28cg

Heads up, I haven't tried this myself, just a guess at this point